# Group counted words in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I list of words. I count them using:

```
cnt = Counter()
 for word in keywords:
  cnt[word] += 1
  cnt
```

After using this code my words look like:

> android :3
>   windows :2
>   apple :5
>   samsung :2
>   motorola :2
>   iphone :3
>   nokia :5
>   alcatel :1

and now I would like to group it, result should look like below:

> 5 : apple
>   3 : android iphone
>   2 : windows samsung motorola
>   1 : alcatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), with the default factory set to a `list`, then feed the `Counter` to it

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in cnt.items():
     d[value].append(key)     

for key, value in d.items():                                                
   print '{}:{}'.format(key, " ".join(value))                              

2:windows
3:android iphone
5:apple
....
```

As an aside, you should be able to initialize the `Counter` directly, like so

```
cnt = Counter(keywords)
```